# How much health does the green buff around neutral minions give you?

Tags: league-of-legends

How much health does the green buff around neutral minions give you? It's really a useful thing to know because then, I could judge whether or not to risk it.

Answer (score 2):

The formula is (25+(5*maxlevel))*1,(%health missing)
So if your lvl 1 and full hp you will get 30 hp, and if your hp is 50% then you will get 45hp
Tested it a few weeks ago because i wondered myself.

Comment: Please add a source.

Answer (score 1):

It gives hp based upon your max lvl teammate, just like the monsters gain health per champ lvl

Answer (score 0):

The lower hp you are, the more hp it restores. I don`t believe Riot has released an exact formula for how much hp the sigil restores.